# Changing variable with jQuery tabs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Google style instant search script written in jQuery which pulls results from a PHP script. I want to make a script so I can change the destination of the file by clicking a certain link. How can I make it so when a certain link is clicked it changes the selected.tab variable to the name of the search type. How can I do this?

Here is my jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#query").keyup(function(){
            var query=$(this).val();
            var yt_url=''+selected.tab+'.php?q='+query;
            window.location.hash=''+selected.tab+'/'+query+'/';
            document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";
            if(query==''){
                  window.location.hash='';
                  document.title='My Search Script';
            }
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:yt_url,
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(results){
                   $('#results').html(results);
                }
            });
    });
    if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#'+selected.tab+'/')==0){
        query = window.location.hash.replace('#'+selected.tab+'/', '').replace('/', '');
        $('#query').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, the `selected` variable seems to be global, so:

```
<a id="change" href="#">change</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#change').click(function() {
  selected.tab = "somethingelse";
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can do it old fashion way: `<a href="javascript:void(selected = 'something_else')">change 1</a> <a href="javascript:void(selected = 'something_different')">change 2</a> `